# How to perform a dry-run using rsync over ssh?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I got these errors while trying to perform a dry-run with option `-n` over ssh on a remote server:

```
# rsync --progress --delete -avhHen ssh /etc/yum root@my.ipaddress:/etc
rsync: Failed to exec n: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.0]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

How do I perform a dry-run for the above command using rsync over ssh?

Comment: You need `-e 'ssh -opts user@host'` or to read the `USING RSYNC-DAEMON FEATURES VIA A REMOTE-SHELL CONNECTION` section in `man rsync`. You can use `--dry-run` or `-n` or `--list-only` for no-op tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rsync: Failed to exec n: No such file or directory (2)
```

Pretty much explains it there...

the `-e` option (long version: --rsh=) says to execute the **FOLLOWING** command as the shell on the destination machine.

You told it: `-e n`.  Look at the order of the options you supplied. (`-avhHen`)

Reverse the order, `ne` so that your redundant use of `-e ssh` will work as you desire.

Comment: Ah.. I get what the error is trying to tell me now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just a minor comment: `-e` specifies the command to get to a remote shell from your local machine. Your answer can be misunderstood that `-e` specifies the path to a shell on the remote machine (e.g. `/usr/bin/bash`) -- which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that [rsync's `-e` option](https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) expects the remote shell as the very next "thing" on the command line: here, that's `n`, while before it was `ssh`.

Usually I'd split -e out as its own option and write this like:

```
rsync --progress --delete -avhHn -e ssh /etc/yum root@my.ipaddress:/etc
```

but you could also just move the `n` earlier - it's important that the `e` be the **last** option in a group of short options, if you're going to use it like that.